# why names containing dot are not taken in consideration in the result list using the command "apt-cache pkgnames <name>"

Tags: bash, package-management, apt-cache

System: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

If you run the following command

```
 $ apt-cache pkgnames python
```

```
.
.
.
python3-case
python3-rpy2
python3-pycurl-dbg
python3-structlog
python-natsort
python-protobuf
python-rpm
python-starpy
python3-rpyc
python-nbxmpp-doc
python-rpy
python-jpylyzer-doc
python-bottle-doc
python-logbook
python-pyside.qthelp
python-agate-doc
```

The result list skip packages names like `python3.7 python3.7-venv python3.6 python3.6-venv`, I mean all packages names containing dot.

We have to run explicitly the below command to list all python packages containing dot in their names.

```
$ apt-cache pkgnames python3.
```

```
python3.7-venv
python3.6-venv
python3.6-examples
python3.6
python3.7
python3.7-dbg
python3.7-dev
python3.7-doc
python3.7-minimal
python3.6-minimal
python3.7-examples
python3.6-dbg
python3.6-dev
python3.6-doc
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic   KDE Neon is not Ubuntu, nor official flavor of Ubuntu thus off-topic on this site...

Comment: @guiverc Although technically true this question applies to all Debian based distributions that use `apt`.

Comment: It looks like your terminal output is truncated. The lists you show only list the last 16 packages. If you grep any package from the first list when you run the second command you should return a result. You need to either set your terminal's preferences to change the number of scrollback lines or  pipe the output to `less` like this instead: `apt-cache pkgnames python | less` You will be able to use your arrow keys to scroll down this list and use Q to quit when you are done.

Comment: @mchid There are over 4,000 python packages as my answer below shows. Scrolling would be cumbersome. But it appears OP is correct the method doesn't show all python3.x packages in the first instance.

Comment: No the OP is wrong, all the 3.6 and 3.7 names are included in the output of apt-cache pkgnames python (buried in all the other names). Try "apt-cache pkgnames python | grep 3\.[67]"

Comment: Thanks pals, really useful the command `apt-cache pkgnames python | grep 3\.[67]` , it realize me that names including dot are in the result of the command, and yes  is very cumbersome to scrolling line by line using ` apt-cache pkgnames python | less` and yes seems the terminal output is being truncated.

Comment: Please edit the answer and add the regular expresion option  to accept the answer.

Comment: @mchid Thank you for upvoting but my answer was incorrect so I deleted it.